# Counting comma separated characters in a row

Tags: sed, awk

How can I count how many elements are separated with comma in a given column of a file (tab_delimited), using awk or sed?

Exemple:

```
AC    1,23,5
DC    2,8,89
```

Would return:

```
AC    3
DC    3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ awk -F '[\t,]' '{print $1, NF-1}' some_file
```

where

- `-F` sets the field separator, i.e. either tab or comma
- `$1` references the first field
- `NF` is a built-in variable that contains the number of fields in a record
- the awk statement is executed for each record (i.e. for each line)

Comment: Very nice. I just found that in case there is no field separator in a line, `NF` is zero, so had to replace `NF-1` by `NF ? NF-1 : 0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -v col=2 -F '\t' '{$col=gsub(",", "", $col)+1; print}'
```

`col` is a parameter representing the analyzed column number and `-v` assigns 2 to it.

`-F '\t'` sets the field separator to the tab character<sup>1</sup>. [`gsub`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) returns the number of substitutions, so it's being used to count the number of commas. The result is assigned to analyzed column and the final `print` displays all the columns.

```
$ cat input 
AC  1,23,5
DC  2,8,89
XX  3,4,5,6,7   YYY,ZZZ
$ awk --assign col=2 -F '\t' '{$col=gsub(",", "", $col)+1; print}' < input
AC 3
DC 3
XX 5 YYY,ZZZ
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> Some awk implementations might not parse `\t` and in that case you can use some Bash specific [quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) - `$'\t'` - which will pass the tab character itself to awk.</sub>

Comment: What significance has the `$` before `'\t'` ? Testing your command without it gives the same results, at least with `gawk` and `nawk`.

Comment: @maxschlepzig, see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374239/tab-separated-values-in-awk#comment23678233_5376527) from Stack Overflow. I got the `$` from over there. It also made no difference for me too with bash-4.2.47-2.fc20.x86_64.

Comment: I see - then it is only needed for `awk` versions  that don't interpret the 2 character string `\t` as tab-character field separator.

Comment: @maxschlepzig, I've removed the `$` to make the command line more portable, less Bash specific. By the way, [Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) has a better explanation than the ABS guide: "Of these, `$'...'` is the most common, and acts just like single quotes except that backslash-escaped combinations are expanded as specified by the ANSI C standard".